# Rails collection_select, populate drop down field using DB data and arbitrary value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, slim-lang, form-helpers

This is more of a curiosity question.

I'm using the the following expression

```
f.collection_select :location_id, current_provider.locations, :id, :to_s, { include_blank: true}, class: 'form-control'
```

(in a `slim` file) to pull up all the location data from the DB, and populate a drop-down menu.

**What I'm curious of**, is if it's possible to have the DB data in one section of the drop down menu, **and** an arbitrary default location in another section of the drop down menu.

Looking forward to hear from the community.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If the arbitrary default location isn't something stored in the locations table in your database, then no, this won't work. This is because `location_id` is a foreign key column, so the only thing it can store is an id from the locations table. Anything besides that or NULL will cause it to throw an error.

If the location *is* stored in the locations table, then you should check out the [`select`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.0/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-select) helper as opposed to `collection_select`. It lets you manipulate the options. You'd do something like

```
f.select :location_id, options_manipulated_however, { include_blank: true}, class: 'form-control'
```